# How do I use Date.setMonth()?

Tags: javascript

I came across this code in a file I am working on for a freelance project of mine:

```
// Get the results from 1st April this year. 
var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(3);
d.setDate(1);
d.setHours(0,59,59,0);
```

I am a noob junior developer so I am sorry if this is basic, I am just curious.

Am I right to believe that Javascript months are always 1 behind. So is this actually getting it from 1 1st March?

Should this be:

```
d.setMonth(2);
```

Comment: Months in `Date` start from 0; so January is 0, February is 1, and so on.

Comment: Look at [JavaScript setMonth() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setmonth.asp)

Comment: The most valuable skill you can learn as a junior developer is to Google things. "javascript date setmonth" gives what you need in the first result.

Answer (score 1):

March is actually 2, not 3. Months start from 0 in JavaScript.

> **monthValue**
>
> An integer between 0 and 11, representing the months January through December.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth

Comment: The code in the first block does exactly what is documented (at least calculates the correct 1st of April). So where is he right? The suggested `d.setMonth(2)` is wrong. This actually gets the 1st March but I believe this is not what is wanted here according to the comment.

Comment: "Am I right to believe that Javascript months are always 1 behind. So is this actually getting it from 1 1st March?" That's what I am answering to. Months go from 0 to 11, so yes, he is right. March is 2.

Comment: "So is this actually getting it from 1 1st March?" This part is wrong.